# Dilemma about value of limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^x+\left(\tan(x)\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right]$$

Attempt: I used $\tan(x)\approx x$ also $(1+n)^{1/n}=e$ so I let $x=0+h$ and lim changes to lim h tending to $0$. But that gives me $e+\infty+h^{1/h}$. While the answer is an integer between $0-9$ . Where is my mistake?.Thanks

Comment: first use the change of variable $u=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+n)^{1/n} = e$ is wrong.

Comment: X is tending to $0$?. Can you explain?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} (1/x)^x = \infty$ is wrong.

Comment: @julio godoy I tried it. I am still stuck

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1/x)^x = e$, but $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+1/x)^x \ne e$

Comment: @GEdgar Perhaps it would be helpful to explain the error to the user. Just saying "X is wrong" comes off as brusk to me.

Comment: The question was not, "how to do it".  The question was, "where is my mistake".

Comment: There is no purpose in doing $x=0+h$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be losing yourself among infinitesimals, I can suggest a safer way; when exponentials are involved, passing to the logarithm is often simpler.

Besides, the substitution $x=0+h$ is of no consequence.

Consider
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\log\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\right)=
\lim_{x\to0^+}x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}=0
$$
Moreover
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\log\bigl((1/x)^x\bigr)=
\lim_{x\to0^+}-x\log x=0
$$
Similarly,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\log\bigl((\tan x)^{1/x}\bigr)=
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\log\tan x}{x}=-\infty
$$
Thus your limit is
$$
1+1+0
$$

Comment: but $lim_{x->0^{+}}\log x=-\infty$?

Comment: @juliogodoy Yes, and so? It's well known that $\lim_{x\to0}x\log x=0$.

Comment: Perfect approach! +1 whenever we have to deal with limits of expressions of type $\{f(x)\}^{g(x)}$ then it is better to take logs. It simplifies the overall calculation a lot.

Comment: Thanks got it so moral is using logs!

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x&=e^{x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}\\\\
&=e^{x\left(\log(1+x)-\log(x)\right)}\\\\
&=e^{-x\log(x)}e^{x\log(1+x)}
\end{align}$$

Since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log(x)=0$, we find using the continuity of the exponential function that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=1$$

---

To evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac1x\right)^x$, we proceed as before.  We write simply

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac1x\right)^x&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{-x\log(x)}\\\\&=1
\end{align}$$

---

To evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\tan (x)\right)^{1/x}$, we use the analogous approach and write

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\tan (x)\right)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{\frac1x \log(\tan(x))}$$

Note that $1/x\to \infty$ while $\log(\tan(x))\to -\infty$.  Thus, the product $\frac1x \log(\tan(x)) \to -\infty$ and we find that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\tan (x)\right)^{1/x}=0$$

Comment: But what about $(1/x)^x$

Comment: We can apply the same approach.  $$(1/x)^x=e^{x\log(1/x)}=e^{-x\log(x)}$$The exponent approaches zero.

Comment: Is $\frac{1}{x+1}\le \log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\le \frac1x$ really useful for $x \to 0$?

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for that catch.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Sorry but still I am not getting the point

Answer (score 1):

Note first of all that $(\tan x)^{1/x}\to0^\infty=0$ as $x\to0^+$, so the trickiest-looking part of the limit is actually the easiest.  More formally, $0\le\tan x\le1$ for $0\le x\le\pi/4$ and $1/x\ge4/\pi\gt1$ for $0\lt x\le\pi/4$, so

$$0\le(\tan x)^{1/x}\le\tan x\quad\text{for }0\lt x\le{\pi\over4}$$

and thus $(\tan x)^{1/x}\to0$ as $x\to0^+$ by the squeeze theorem.

As for the rest of the limit, it's convenient to write

$$\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^x+\left(1\over x\right)^x={(x+1)^x+1\over x^x}$$

and then "distribute" the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left[\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^x+\left(1\over x\right)^x\right]={\lim_{x\to0^+}((x+1)^x+1)\over\lim_{x\to0^+}(x^x)}={2\over\lim_{x\to0^+}(x^x)}$$

So all that remains is to show that $\lim_{x\to0^+}(x^x)=1$, which is equivalent to showing

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln x=0$$

Computing this limit without using L'Hopital requires additional steps.  I will omit them here, unless there is a request for them in comments.  (The other answers, I see, took this limit for granted.)